# How to generate multiple folders from git worktree command?

Tags: python, git, cmd, git-worktree

This is my dataframe file witch contain the CommitId:

```
CommitId
d38f7b334856ed4007fb3ec0f8a5f7499ee2f2b8
d38f7b334856ed4007fb3ec0f8a5f7499ee2f2b8
d38f7b334856ed4007fb3ec0f8a5f7499ee2f2b8
4bb968a47ce00279d6051df95bd782650700179e
c3d7ec38417ecff03d1cd3be0163e6ce07578eb3
00568c9886e739d6b5dd61b4a4326d598552fb6f
00568c9886e739d6b5dd61b4a4326d598552fb6f
00568c9886e739d6b5dd61b4a4326d598552fb6f
00568c9886e739d6b5dd61b4a4326d598552fb6f
6e062098453febbfb0169cd0af56f70f2e3fc77f
63f658918c2f4b851b0d0fffbffab4df0cfe13ca
```

I need to checkout each commit and copy the version of code on another directory so for this exemple I need 11 version of code each in a directory so 11 directory with different names

I tried this sample code:

```
import os
from distutils.dir_util import copy_tree
path1='C:/Users/AQ42770/Desktop/RefactoringMiner/bin/Android-ContactPicker'
os.chdir(path1)

commande1='git worktree add C:/Users/AQ42770/Documents/commit d38f7b334856ed4007fb3ec0f8a5f7499ee2f2b8' 
os.system(commande1)

commande2='git worktree add C:/Users/AQ42770/Documents/commit1 
4bb968a47ce00279d6051df95bd782650700179e'
os.system(commande2)
```

But it's not pratical beacause I have a lot of commits for this exemple I have 11 commits for others I have 100+ commits.So I tried this code but it return nothing :

```
n=1
list=["95fe00030ad97c998cd0b1b7df030dcda0db7baa","47b91018e3cb45ee0f7c3135488855554ad6617d"]
path="C:/Users/AQ42770/Documents/commit"
for n in range(0,2):
   t=path+str(n)
   os.system('git worktree add t list[n]')
```

PS:I puted the commits in a list to test first then I will read from the dataframe

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the datafile is `C:/Users/AQ42770/Desktop/mydata.txt`.

```
import os
import re

wortreebase = 'C:/Users/AQ42770/Documents/'
mydata = 'C:/Users/AQ42770/Desktop/mydata.txt'
gitdir = 'C:/Users/AQ42770/Desktop/RefactoringMiner/bin/Android-ContactPicker/.git'

# find all commits
with open(mydata) as f:
    commits = re.findall(r'[0-9a-f]{40}', f.read())

for i, commit in enumerate(commits):
    # name the worktree
    worktree = wortreebase + '%s_%s' % (i, commit))
    # create the worktree
    cmd = 'git --git-dir=%s worktree add %s %s' % (gitdir, worktree, commit)
    os.system(cmd)
```